# splitable data structure (in c++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, split, structure

I wonder if anybody could help me out.

I look for a data structure (such as list, queue, stack, array, vector, binary tree etc.) supporting these four operations:

- **isEmpty** (true/false)
- **insert** single element
- **pop** (i.e. get&remove) single element
- **split** into two structures e.g. take a approximately half (let's say +/- 20%) of elements and move them to another structure

**Note** that I don't care about order of elements at all.

Insert/pop example:

```
A.insert(1), A.insert(2), A.insert(3), A.insert(4), A.insert(5) // contains 1,2,3,4,5 in any order
A.pop() // 3
A.pop() // 2
A.pop() // 5
A.pop() // 1
A.pop() // 4
```

and the split example:

```
A.insert(1), A.insert(2), A.insert(3), A.insert(4), A.insert(5)
A.split(B)
// A = {1,4,3}, B={2,5} in any order
```

I need the structure to be be fast as possible - preferably all four operations in O(1). I doubt it have been already implemented in std so I will implement it by myself (in C++11, so `std::move` can be used).

**Note** that *insert*, *pop* and *isEmpty* are called about ten times more frequently than *split*.

I tried [some coding](http://pastebin.com/1rMteVYK) with `list` and `vector` but with no success:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11
/*
output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
5 6 7 8 9
*/

int main ()
{
        std::vector<int> v1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) v1.push_back(i);

        for (auto i : v1) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        auto halfway = v1.begin() + v1.size() / 2;
        auto endItr  = v1.end();

        std::vector<int> v2;
        v2.insert(v2.end(),
                std::make_move_iterator(halfway),
                std::make_move_iterator(endItr));

        // sigsegv
        /*
        auto halfway2 = v1.begin() + v1.size() / 2;
        auto endItr2  = v1.end();
        v2.erase(halfway2, endItr2);
        */

        for (auto i : v1) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (auto i : v2) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Any sample code, ideas, links or whatever useful? Thanks

**Related literature:**

- [How to move the later half of a vector into another vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938889/how-to-move-the-later-half-of-a-vector-into-another-vector) (actually does not work due to deletetion problem)
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/move_iterator/

Comment: `I tried some coding with list and vector but with no success.` what do you have so far?

Comment: please see http://pastebin.com/1rMteVYK

Comment: How exactly does the split need to be in the middle? How important is cache efficiency (as provided by contiguous containers such as `vector`)? How many bytes are you usually storing when you split?

Comment: If you can tolerate to split *not exactly* in the middle, it can be done faster than O(n), see my answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a container I just wrote to do all operations in O(log n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems with the deletion aare due to a bug in your code.

```
// sigsegv
auto halfway2 = v1.begin() + v1.size() / 2;
auto endItr2  = v1.end();
v2.erase(halfway2, endItr2);
```

You try to erase from `v2` with iterators pointing into `v1`. That won't work and you probably wanted to call`erase` on `v1`.

That fixes your deletion problem when splitting the vector, and vector seems to be the best container for what you want.

Note that everything except split can be done in O(1) on a vector if you insert at the end only, but since order doesn't matter for you I don't see any problem with it, split would be O(n) in your implemention once you fixed it, but that should be pretty fast since the data is right next to eachother in the vector and that's very cache friendly.

Comment: @Walter why wouldn't it answer the question? A vector is in cases like OP's often the most performant. Also he said that vector didn't work due to problems with deleting, but that was only a bug on his side which I fixed.

Comment: a `vector::push_back()` is only amortized O(1). Well, whether a vector is best depends somewhat on the number of elements. Vector will be good for many elements and infrequent splits.

Comment: @Walter that's something OP should definately measure like everything concerning speed. But given the limited information it's definately viable, if only to compare to other. It's simple and implementing it for some measurements shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 2):

I can’t think of a solution with all operations in O(1).

With a **list** you can have push and pop in O(1), and split in O(n) (due to the fact that you need to find the middle of the list).

With a **balanced binary tree** (not a search tree) you can have all operations in O(log n).

**edit**

There have been some suggestions that keeping the middle of the list would produce O(1). This is not the case as when you split the function you have to compute the middle of the left list and the middle of the right list resulting in O(n).

Some other suggestion is that a vector is preferred simply because it is cache-friendly.  I totally agree with this.

For fun, I implemented a balanced binary tree container that performs all operations in O(log n). The `insert` and `pop` are obviously in O(log n). The actual split is in O(1), however we are left with the root node which we have to insert in one of the halves resulting in O(log n) for `split` also. No copying is involved however.

Here is my attempt at the said container (I haven’t thoroughly tested for correctness, and it can be further optimized (like transforming the recursion in a loop)).

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>

template <class T>
class BalancedBinaryTree {
  private:
    class Node;

    std::unique_ptr<Node> root_;

  public:
    void insert(const T &data) {
      if (!root_) {
        root_ = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data));
        return;
      }
      root_->insert(data);
    }

    std::size_t getSize() const {
      if (!root_) {
        return 0;
      }
      return 1 + root_->getLeftCount() + root_->getRightCount();
    }

    // Tree must not be empty!!
    T pop() {
      if (root_->isLeaf()) {
        T temp = root_->getData();
        root_ = nullptr;
        return temp;
      }
      return root_->pop()->getData();
    }

    BalancedBinaryTree split() {
      if (!root_) {
        return BalancedBinaryTree();
      }

      BalancedBinaryTree left_half;
      T root_data = root_->getData();
      bool left_is_bigger = root_->getLeftCount() > root_->getRightCount();

      left_half.root_ = std::move(root_->getLeftChild());
      root_ = std::move(root_->getRightChild());

      if (left_is_bigger) {
        insert(root_data);
      } else {
        left_half.insert(root_data);
      }

      return std::move(left_half);
    }
};


template <class T>
class BalancedBinaryTree<T>::Node {
  private:
    T data_;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left_child_, right_child_;
    std::size_t left_count_ = 0;
    std::size_t right_count_ = 0;

  public:
    Node() = default;
    Node(const T &data, std::unique_ptr<Node> left_child = nullptr,
         std::unique_ptr<Node> right_child = nullptr)
        : data_(data), left_child_(std::move(left_child)),
         right_child_(std::move(right_child)) {
    }

    bool isLeaf() const {
      return left_count_ + right_count_ == 0;
    }

    const T& getData() const {
      return data_;
    }
    T& getData() {
      return data_;
    }

    std::size_t getLeftCount() const {
      return left_count_;
    }

    std::size_t getRightCount() const {
      return right_count_;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> &getLeftChild() {
      return left_child_;
    }
    const std::unique_ptr<Node> &getLeftChild() const {
      return left_child_;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Node> &getRightChild() {
      return right_child_;
    }
    const std::unique_ptr<Node> &getRightChild() const {
      return right_child_;
    }

    void insert(const T &data) {
      if (left_count_ <= right_count_) {
        ++left_count_;
        if (left_child_) {
          left_child_->insert(data);
        } else {
          left_child_ = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data));
        }
      } else {
        ++right_count_;
        if (right_child_) {
          right_child_->insert(data);
        } else {
          right_child_ = std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(data));
        }
      }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Node> pop() {
      if (isLeaf()) {
        throw std::logic_error("pop invalid path");
      }

      if (left_count_ > right_count_) {
        --left_count_;
        if (left_child_->isLeaf()) {
          return std::move(left_child_);
        }
        return left_child_->pop();
      }

      --right_count_;
      if (right_child_->left_count_ == 0 && right_child_->right_count_ == 0) {
        return std::move(right_child_);
      }
      return right_child_->pop();
    }
};
```

usage:

```
  BalancedBinaryTree<int> t;
  BalancedBinaryTree<int> t2;

  t.insert(3);
  t.insert(7);
  t.insert(17);
  t.insert(37);
  t.insert(1);

  t2 = t.split();

  while (t.getSize() != 0) {
    std::cout << t.pop() << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  while (t2.getSize() != 0) {
    std::cout << t2.pop() << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
```

output:

```
1 17
3 37 7
```

Comment: I agree. but this should be a comment.

Comment: I'd go for a vector, order doesn't matter so everything can be done in O(1) at the end, except split. But vector is very cache friendly and it should therefore still be really fast.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of elements/bytes stored at any one time in your container is large, the solution of Youda008 (using a list and keeping track of the middle) may not be as efficient as you hope.

Alternatively, you could have a `list<vector<T>>` or even `list<array<T,Capacity>>` **and** keep track of the middle of the list, i.e. split only between two sub-containers, but never split a sub-container. This should give you both O(1) on all operations and reasonable cache efficiency. Use `array<T,Capacity>` if a single value for `Capacity` serves your needs at all times (for `Capacity=1`, this reverts to an ordinary `list`).
Otherwise, use `vector<T>` and adapt the capacity for new vectors according to demand.

*bolov*'s points out correctly that finding the middles of the lists emerging from splitting one list is not O(1). This implies that keeping track of the middle is not useful. However, using a `list<sub_container>` is still **faster than list**, because the split only costs **O(n/`Capacity`) not O(n)**. The price you pay for this is that the split has a graininess of `Capacity` rather than 1. Thus, you must compromise between the accuracy and cost of a split.

Comment: same as @Youda008: when you split you have to compute the middle of the left list and the middle of the right list.

Comment: I wrote a container (tree) with O(log n). I am curious how that would compare with your solution and with straight vector. Your solution reminds me somehow of a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to implement own container using a linked list and a pointer to that middle element, at which you want to split it. This pointer will be updated on every modifying operation. This way you can achieve O(1) complexicity on all operations.

Comment: you can’t achieve O(1). When you split (let’s say you have the middle of the list), you have to get the middle of the left list and the middle of the right list : O(n).

Comment: @bolov you can easily do it in fact with a list when you already got the iterator to the middle container. Just put the begin/end pointers of the new list to the middle item pointed to by that iterator and the end pointer of the original list respectively. The end pointer for the original list to the middle item. Voila, 3 pointer changes, no matter how long the list.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl for a list, getting the middle between two pointers is not O(1).

Comment: @Walter indeed, it only is O(1) if you already got a pointer/iterator to the middle. That said, I'm not really for such a implementation.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I'm not sure I understand or agree with you. You cannot use the trick of keeping track of the middle to avoid the O(n) costs for the split a lists. The costs come in by the back door when you need the middles of the split products (i.e. the quartiles of the original container).

Comment: ah yea, sorry, dumb answer :(